# Putting a value from model into an HTML style attribute via Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to display a series of `div`s in my view, the `width` of each being dependent on the amount of items in a child list in my viewmodel. I'm determining what the width of the `div`s ought to be in my controller and am trying to alter the `width` of the `div`s in my view by changing the value of the HTML `style` attribute. However, I can't seem to insert a value from my model into a `style` attribute in the same way I can insert it into a class attribute. Here's a little bit of my code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.IntegrationActivityList.Count; i++)
{
    <div data-integration-id="@Model.IntegrationActivityList[i].WorkflowIntegrationActivityParentId" style="width:@Model.IntegrationActivityList[i].IntegrationActivityDivWidth;">
        /* more code here, iterate through child list items */
    </div>
}
```

`data-integration-id="@Model.IntegrationActivityList[i].WorkflowIntegrationActivityParentId"` works fine, but `style="width:@Model.IntegrationActivityList[i].IntegrationActivityDivWidth;"` does not result in a rendered `style` attribute at all.

I've tried a couple other methods, such as using Html.Raw to generate the markup, also to no avail: `<div @Html.Raw("style='width: " + Model.IntegrationActivityList[i].IntegrationActivityDivWidth + ";'")>`.

How can I modify the `width` of my `div` using Razor and information from my model? (I'm also open to any other suggestions on better ways to accomplish this.)

Comment: can you try removing style. eg. "width=@Model.IntegrationActivityList[i].IntegrationActivityDivWidth;">
        /* more code here, iterate through child list items */ And your width value should end with px or %

Comment: Thanks, I added 'px' to the end of my viewmodel property. However, the width HTML attribute doesn't seem to work, I think because my divs are inline-blocks.

Comment: Is your browser rendering width attribute with value? where have you specified the div as inline-block? The width can be specified for inline-block as well

Comment: Hi, yeah, it's rendering the `width` attribute with the value. I could be wrong but the `width` attribute doesn't seem to be working with an `inline-block`: [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z85dgbu2/). Also, my `div` elements are absolutely positioned which appears to be preventing the `width` attribute from working as well.

Comment: if you specify style="width:400px", its working. so can you readd the style attribute and check

Comment: Specifying `style="width:400px"` does indeed work great, but the issue I'm having is, with the code I'm using above, the `style` attribute is not rendering in my markup at all, whereas the `data-integration-id` is rendering without a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112435/discussion-between-karthik-m-r-and-pinhead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the `@Html.Raw()` function call inside the `style` attribute like so:

```
<div style="@Html.Raw("width:" + Model.IntegrationActivityList[i].IntegrationActivityDivWidth + ";")"></div>
```